# Variável retornando null apenas no Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Tenho o seguinte pedaço de código:

```
var cta = document.querySelector('.cta');
```

No Chrome/Opera ele retorna o elemento corretamente, apenas no Firefox ele está me retornado o erro :

```
TypeError: cta is null
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Estou chamando ele via:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    cta.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

Código completo:

```
var cta = document.querySelector('.cta');

function box() {
    if(cta) {
        var vitrine = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.vitrine'));
        for(var i = 0; i < vitrine.length; i++) {
            vitrine[i].style.height = window.getComputedStyle(vitrine[i]).width;
        }
    }
}

box();

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    cta.style.opacity = 1;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => box());
```

Comment: Podes fazer um exemplo a funcionar aqui ou no jsFiddle? O que acontece se `var cta = document.querySelector('.cta');` também estiver dentro desse `load`?

Comment: Qual é versão do seu Firefox? eu testei agora na versão 47.0.2 é funcionou corretamente. Na própria de documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector é possível encontrar que a mozilla da suporte ao querySelector

Comment: Poderia colocar uma parte maior do código para que possamos analisar melhor?

Comment: Seria muito trabalhoso colocar no jsFiddle e sim realmente se eu colocar esse pedaço de código no Firefox ele funciona, vou atualizar a pergunta com o codigo completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu código está no `<head>`, ele é carregado antes do `<body>`. Assim, quando você seleciona um elemento fora de algum evento que garanta o carregamento do DOM, você terá como retorno ***null***, já que o elemento ainda não existe.

[Exemplo no JsFiddle - **Retorno *null*** - Load Type: No wrap in **Head**](https://jsfiddle.net/h52kv53w/)

Você pode mudar isso ao armazenar seu elemento na variável, dentro do callback do evento *load* no objeto **window**, ou do evento *DOMContentLoaded* do objeto **document**.

[Exemplo no JsFiddle - **Retorno *correto*** - Load Type: No wrap in **Head**](https://jsfiddle.net/5q3mgx14/)

Ou colocando seu código dentro do `body`, no final da página:

[Exemplo no JsFiddle - **Retorno *correto*** - Load Type: No wrap in **Body**](https://jsfiddle.net/j65wc5oh/)

Comment: Nossa. Isso mesmo! Gzuz que erro amador o meu. Muito obrigado!