# Qual é a finalidade da função "ready()"?

Tags: jquery

Em scripts escritos em jQuery eu sempre me deparo com uma função que é a função `ready()`, como a primeira função a ser executa, veja um exemplo de ilustração dela:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnexemplo").click(function () {
                alert("meow");
            });
        });
</script>
<button id="btnexemplo">Click aqui!</button>
```

A função `ready()` parece pertencer ao `$(document)`, não sei se ele é um objeto, e se eu remover ela o evento de click não dispara.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade da função `ready()` e qual é a importância dela em relação aos scripts escritos usando a biblioteca jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `.ready()`, como diz a documentação do Jquery:

> [...] oferece uma maneira de executar o código JavaScript assim que o Document Object Model (DOM) da página esteja pronto para ser manipulado.

Ou seja, é um evento.

Funciona como uma aproximação do evento *"DOMContentLoaded"*

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
```

Quando o DOM (árvore de elementos da página) estiver **totalmente carregado e pronto para receber estilos, eventos e modificações na [pipeline](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/)** o callback será chamado.

A diferença básica entre os dois é que o `.ready()`, se for chamado após a página já estiver carregada, ele **ainda executará o callback**. Por exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Página já carregada */
  $('div').css({
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#333'
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    /* A página já carregou, mas o evento ainda é constantemente executado */
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('div').css({
        background: 'red'
      })
    })    
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

O que não acontece com o `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.background = "#333";
  setTimeout(function(){
    
    /* O evento não vai ser chamado dessa vez, pois isso só acontece no carregamento inicial da página. */ 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      div.style.background = "#fff";
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div></div>
```

A principal vantagem do `.ready()`, ao meu ver, nesse quesito, a inserção de códigos dinâmico de terceiros, APIs e etc, que poderão ser chamadas com a garantia de que a página já está carregada, e não necessariamente na sua primeira chamada.

Quando você executa um `.click()`, por exemplo, sem estar dentro do callback, [dependendo de onde está o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173901/vari%C3%A1vel-retornando-null-apenas-no-firefox/173914#173914), o elemento a receber esse *bind*, poderá ainda não estar pronto a receber eventos, pois o DOM pode ainda estar em fase de carregamento.

Basicamente, é uma forma de garantir que a manipulação de elementos seja executado com sucesso.